# Drupal querying database table

Tags: mysql, drupal

I am a  newbie in Drupal, I have a table in a drupal database. I wanted to query all the content of it and display in a tabular format. Whenever I execute the query the link directs me to the blank page and nothing appears. I have attached the  PhP code for the reference. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
   <?php
  $header = array('Name', 'Age', 'Sex','University');
  $rows = array();

  $sql = 'SELECT Name, Age, Sex,University FROM {data_pulling} ORDER BY Name';
  $res = db_query($sql);
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($res)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
  }

  print theme('table', $header, $rows);
?>
```

Comment: a blank page usually means that you had a PHP error of some sort.

Comment: Exactly I view the PHP error it complains about this,  Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_fetch_array() in /var/www/drupal/modules/php/php.module(80). Any idea ?

Comment: which version of Drupal are you using.  dp_fetch_array was removed from Drupal 7 because there is a new database API.

Comment: I am using drupal 7, yes I find out recently that db_fetch_array was not there in the new API of Drupal 7. Thank you very much for your suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess you're using Drupal 7 but are trying to use API functions from Drupal 6.

Try this

```
foreach ($res as $row) {
  $rows[] = (array) $row;
}

print theme('table', array('rows' => $rows, 'header' => $header));
```

Have a look at the [docs for db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) and [theme_table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) for more information